# How to replace a workflow field update by a formula field?

Tags: formula, field-update

I want to replace a field update which has got formula as `TEXT( $User.UserType__c )` by a formula field.

The scenario here is if I create an account a text field called as **Creation Origin** will get the value **"SRC"**.

Comment: Can't you just set the formula to `CreatedBy.UserType__c`?

Answer (score 1):

If the goal of the workflow rule is to set a field based on the person who modified the record then you will need to stick with a workflow rule. The $User Global Variable represents the running user, from the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_understanding_global_variables.htm):

> $User
>
> Description:  A global merge field type to use when referencing
>   information about the current user. User merge fields can reference
>   information about the user such as alias, title, and ID.
>
> Use:
>
> Select the field type: $User.
>
> Select a merge field such as $User.Username.
>
> Validation Rule Example:  The validation rule formula below references
>   the ID of the current user to determine if the current user is the
>   owner of the record. Use an example like this to ensure that only the
>   record owner or users with an administrator profile can make changes
>   to a custom field called Personal Goal:

```
AND( ISCHANGED( Personal_Goal__c ), Owner <> $User.Id, $Profile.Name <>
                  "Custom: System Admin" )
```

> Flow Example: To easily access the running user’s name, use a flow
>   formula. Create a flow formula (Text) that has this expression.

```
{!$User.FirstName} & “ “ & {!$User.LastName}
```

> Once you create that formula, reference it anywhere that you need to
>   call the user by name in your flow. By referencing the $User global
>   variable, you avoid using a lookup, which counts against flow limits.
>
> Visualforce Example:
>
> The following example displays the current user’s company name, as
>   well as the status of the current user (which returns a Boolean
>   value).

```
<apex:page>
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
   This is your new Apex Page
   <p>The current company name for this 
      user is: {!$User.CompanyName}</p>
   <p>Is the user active?  
      {!$User.isActive}</p>
</apex:page>
```

> Tips:
>
> The current user is the person changing the record that prompted the
>   default value, validation rule, or other operation that uses these
>   global merge fields.
>
> When a Web-to-Case or Web-to-Lead process changed a record, the
>   current user is the Default Lead Owner or Default Case Owner.
>
> When a process executes scheduled actions and the user who started the
>   process is no longer active, $User refers to the default workflow
>   user. The same goes for time-based actions in workflow rules.
>
> Some of the $User merge fields can be used in mobile configuration
>   filters.